# How to use RSpec to test that a method catches a symbol?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can you test that a method catches a thrown symbol in RSpec? I have two methods that interact with each other through #throw and #catch. I already figured out how to test that the symbol is thrown on one end:

```
expect { subject.method_a }.to throw_symbol(:some_symbol)
```

Now I want to test that method_b catches the thrown symbol, which I imagine might look something like this:

```
expect { subject.method_b }.to catch_symbol(:some_symbol)
```

Only that doesn't work. So my question is, how can you test that a method catches a symbol in RSpec?

EDIT: Here's a very basic example of method_a and method_b, stripped of all logic not related to the problem at hand.

```
def method_a 
  throw :some_symbol
end

def method_b
  catch :some_symbol do 
    method_a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` and `throw` are methods on Kernel so you can expect them as usual:

```
class SomeClass
  def a
    throw :foo
  end

  def b
    catch :foo do
      a
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe "" do
  it "" do
    inst = SomeClass.new
    expect(inst).to receive(:throw).with(:foo)
    inst.a
    expect(inst).to receive(:catch).with(:foo)
    inst.b
  end
end
```